# Environmental Variable Not Reading in Java

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, system-variable

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. In my user home, I added one environmental variable to **.bashrc** file.

```
export MYCONFIG_HOME=/home/myuser/config-1.0
```

And I run the .bashrc file

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

I open my STS, added the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myHomeVar = System.getenv("MYCONFIG_HOME");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.name"));
        System.out.println(myHomeVar);
    }
```

It gives me following output

```
myuser
null
```

When I do `echo $MYCONFIG_HOME`, it is giving the value. Why is it not getting in the Java program?

Do I need to restart the system? If I have to restart, is there anyway to get the value without restarting the system?

**NOTE:** It got worked when I restarted the system.

Comment: maybe sts forks its own process, and hence does not inherit your shell params.

Comment: So what I have to do? restart?

Comment: Are you launching STS from the same command line where you do the `echo $MYCONFIG_HOME`?

Comment: Nope. It's different. I set the value after starting the STS only. I tried restarting STS. It didn't work. Till now I haven't tried restarting system.

Comment: It got worked when I restarted the system.

Comment: I think you should restart your system, three times to make sure.

Comment: I once restarted and it's working. But my question is why the system needs to restart. Any problem with STS?